# Upload only changed files when publishing via ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have several large files in my ClickOnce installer.  Each time I publish, I have to send up everything.  Is there a way just to copy .deploy files that have changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible, however, you can take those large files, create a separate install application and make that installation a prerequisite to your application by creating a Bootstrapper and adding it to your pool of available prereqs.

The link below discusses the process.

[(MSDN: Creating Bootstrapper Packages)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If it makes you feel any better, if the files haven't changed, they won't be copied across the network to the user machine. It will copy them to the new version's folders from the ClickOnce cache instead.

Comment: That is indeed true.  If it can do that, why can't it check previous versions on upload?  Sigh.

Comment: My guess would be they don't do that because they need all of the files in one folder signed with the same certificate. How would it serve it up to the client if the file is not in the current version's folder? Would it look back successive versions, and hope you didn't delete the version it was first deployed with? Or does it copy it forward on the server each time? What if you changed your signing certificate? Now the file isn't hashed correctly... Basically, it's a can of worms.